# About Tate Cohomology of Cyclic Groups

Tags: group-cohomology, class-field-theory

I got stuck in J.S.Milne's Class Field Theory Chapter 2, Page 79. It is written in the remark that for a cyclic group $G$ with generator $\sigma$.

Let $\gamma$ be the element of $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ corresponding under the isomorphism

$H^2(G,\mathbb{Z})\simeq Hom(G,\mathbb{Q/Z})$

to the map sending the chosen generator $\sigma$ of $G$ to $1/m$. Then the map

$H^r_T(G,M)\to H^{r+2}_T(G,M)$ is just $x \mapsto x\cup\gamma$.

I tried to show this by definition but failed. I have to go back to the exact sequence

$0\to M\to \mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M\to \mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M\to M\to 0$

in the previous page but found it hard to compute with the cohomology $\delta$ functor. By the way, I also have no idea about how to show a homomorphism is just the cup product with this given $\gamma$. So does anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Let me add some new questions here. I continued reading that notes and went on to Page 83. Recall that in Tate's Theorem we get $H^r(G,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{r+2}(G,C)$ is an isomorphism under proper conditions(Conditions about $H^1 vanishing, H^2 being cyclic$) where $C$ is a $G-module$. Then in Remark 3.13 on Page 83, Milne pointed out that the map $H^r(G,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{r+2}(G,C)$ is cup product with the generator of the cyclic group $\gamma \in H^2(G,C)$. Again cup product comes and I still have questions about why this map is just the cup product.